# Background color for layout not setting as WHITE even if selected as WHITE in xml and also in Background Code

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-layout

**Background color for layout not setting as WHITE even if i have selected as WHITE in xml and also in Background Code.**

**i have created White board App for my client. objective of this code is to write anything on board by any color. i have tried many things but not worked please help.**

**Here is my xml Code...**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear"
    android:padding="0dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:foregroundGravity="top"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/undoButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_undo_24"
            android:text="Undo"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_delete_24"
            android:text="Erase"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/redoButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_redo_24"
            android:text="Redo"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/eraserButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:textOff="Pen"
            android:textOn="Eraser"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />


        <View
            android:id="@+id/colorPreview"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/colorpanel"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linear">
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**And Here is Main Activity...**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var drawingView: DrawingView
    private var currentColor = Color.BLUE
    var drawingBackgroundColor: Int = Color.WHITE
    var isEraserMode = false


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val container = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.container)

        drawingView = DrawingView(this)
        container.addView(drawingView)


        val eraserButton = findViewById<ToggleButton>(R.id.eraserButton)
        eraserButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                // Eraser mode is active
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Eraser is Active", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                drawingView.toggleEraserMode(true)
            } else {
                // Eraser mode is not active (pen mode)
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Pen is Active", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                drawingView.toggleEraserMode(false)
            }
        }


        val colorPreview = findViewById<View>(R.id.colorPreview)
        //colorPreview.setBackgroundColor(currentColor)
        //colorPreview.setPadding(12, 12, 12, 12)
        colorPreview.elevation = 4f

        colorPreview.setOnClickListener {
            showColorPickerDialog()
        }



        val deleteButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.deleteButton)
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener {
            drawingView.clearCanvas()
        }

        val undoButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.undoButton)
        undoButton.setOnClickListener {
            drawingView.undo()
        }

        val redoButton = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.redoButton)
        redoButton.setOnClickListener {
            drawingView.redo()
        }

        //=============

        //====


    }



    private fun showColorPickerDialog() {
        val colorPicker = AmbilWarnaDialog(this, currentColor, object : AmbilWarnaDialog.OnAmbilWarnaListener {
            override fun onCancel(dialog: AmbilWarnaDialog) {
                // Do nothing
            }

            override fun onOk(dialog: AmbilWarnaDialog, color: Int) {
                currentColor = color
                drawingView.setDrawColor(currentColor)
                findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.container).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
            }
        })

        colorPicker.show()
    }

    data class DrawingAction1(val path: Path, val color: Int)

    inner class DrawingView(context: android.content.Context) : View(context) {
        private val drawingActions = mutableListOf<DrawingAction1>() // List to store drawing actions
        private var currentActionIndex = -1
        private val paint = Paint()
        private lateinit var bitmap: Bitmap
        private lateinit var canvas: Canvas
        private var eraserSize = 30f
        private val penSize = 5f
        private val pathList = mutableListOf<Pair<Path, Int>>() // List to store drawn paths and their colors
        private var currentPath = Path()


        init {
            paint.color = currentColor
            paint.isAntiAlias = true
            paint.strokeWidth = 5f
            paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
            paint.strokeJoin = Paint.Join.ROUND
            paint.strokeCap = Paint.Cap.ROUND
            //setBackgroundColor(drawingBackgroundColor)
            setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)
            val initialEraserSize = 30f
            eraserSize = initialEraserSize
        }

        override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
            // Clear the canvas and redraw all drawing actions
            canvas.drawColor(drawingBackgroundColor, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR)
            for (i in 0 until currentActionIndex + 1) {
                val drawingAction = drawingActions[i]
                if (drawingAction.color == drawingBackgroundColor) {
                    // Set the stroke width only for eraser actions
                    paint.strokeWidth = eraserSize
                } else {
                    // Set the regular stroke width for non-eraser actions
                    paint.strokeWidth = penSize
                }
                paint.color = drawingAction.color
                canvas.drawPath(drawingAction.path, paint)
            }
        }

        override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
            canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        }

        @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
        override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            val x = event.x
            val y = event.y

            when (event.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    if (currentActionIndex < drawingActions.size - 1) {
                        drawingActions.subList(currentActionIndex + 1, drawingActions.size).clear()
                    }
                    currentPath = Path()
                    currentPath.moveTo(x, y)
                    val drawColor = if (isEraserMode) drawingBackgroundColor else currentColor
                    val drawStrokeWidth = if (isEraserMode) eraserSize else penSize
                    paint.strokeWidth = drawStrokeWidth
                    pathList.add(Pair(currentPath, drawColor))
                    drawingActions.add(DrawingAction1(currentPath, drawColor))
                    currentActionIndex++
                    return true
                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                    currentPath.lineTo(x, y)
                    invalidate()
                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                    currentPath.lineTo(x, y)
                    invalidate()
                }
            }
            invalidate()
            return true
        }

        fun clearCanvas() {
            drawingActions.clear()
            currentActionIndex = -1
            invalidate()
        }

        fun undo() {
            if (currentActionIndex >= 0) {
                currentActionIndex--
                invalidate()
            }
        }

        fun redo() {
            if (currentActionIndex < drawingActions.size - 1) {
                currentActionIndex++
                invalidate()
            }
        }

        fun setDrawColor(color: Int) {
            paint.color = color
        }


        fun toggleEraserMode(eraserMode: Boolean) {
            isEraserMode = eraserMode
            if (eraserMode) {
                paint.color = drawingBackgroundColor // Set the paint color to the background color for eraser mode
                paint.strokeWidth = eraserSize // Set the eraser size
            } else {
                paint.color = currentColor // Set the paint color to the current drawing color
                paint.strokeWidth = penSize // Set the regular stroke width
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: ScreenShot will help to understand your problem. First of all try with a different (eg. red) color.